# CMTimeMake(duration, fps). What is this mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

I am making video file on my Mac programmatically.
I want to know that "CMtimeMake" is what's mean.

For example:

```
AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor * avAdaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:NULL];

[avAdaptor appendPixelBufferixelBuffer withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake(1, 10)];
```

Comment: Do a search on "CMtimeMake" in the Xcode help system. It explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

`CMTimeMake` makes a valid `CMTime` with value and timescale.

Here in your code:

```
CMTimeMake(1,10)
```

A `CMTime` is represented as a rational number, with a numerator (an int64_t value), and a denominator (an int32_t timescale).

`CMTimeMake` is called to create `CMTime` representing times(either durations or timestamps).

1 is the value field of the resulting `CMTime` and 10 means each unit represents a tenth of a second.